# What is the purpose of `pub` in decl_storage?

Tags: substrate, parity-io

When implementing a runtime module in substrate, given the following storage

```rust
decl_storage! {
  trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as CatAuction {
    Kitties get(kitties): map T::Hash => Kitty<T::Hash, T::Balance>;
    KittyOwner get(owner_of): map T::Hash => Option<T::AccountId>;
    OwnedKitties get(kitties_owned): map T::AccountId => T::Hash;

    pub AllKittiesCount get(all_kitties_cnt): u64;
    Nonce: u64;

    // if you want to initialize value in storage, use genesis block
  }
}
```

What is the purpose of `pub` in front of `AllKittiesCount`? Because whether there is `pub` or not, polkadot UI can still query it, as if it is a public variable.

Comment: Do we tell you to use `pub` somewhere in our tutorials? Or is this just a side question?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi  Going through the [decl_storage! doc](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support_procedural/macro.decl_storage.html), saying Basic storage can be extended as such:
`#vis #name get(#getter) config(#field_name) build(#closure): #type = #default;`
`#vis: Set the visibility of the structure. pub or nothing` ...

Comment: This is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902167/in-substrate-is-there-a-way-to-use-storage-and-functions-from-one-custom-module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand here a bit, just like any Rust type, you need to be explicit about the visibility of different types. The `decl_storage` macro generates a `struct` for each of your storage items. For example:

```rust
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
        Something get(something): u32;
    }
}
```

Would result in (some stuff removed for clarity):

```rust
struct Something<T: Trait>(...);

impl <T: Trait> ... for Something<T> {
    fn get<S: ... >(storage: &S) -> Self::Query {
        storage.get(...).unwrap_or_else(|| Default::default())
    }
    fn take<S: ...>(storage: &S) -> Self::Query {
        storage.take(...).unwrap_or_else(|| Default::default())
    }
    fn mutate<R, F: FnOnce(&mut Self::Query) -> R, S: ...>(f: F, storage: &S) -> R {
        let mut val = <Self as ...>::get(storage);
        let ret = f(&mut val);
        <Self as ...>::put(&val, storage);
        ret
    }
}
```

If you make the storage item `pub` you simply introduce a `pub` tag to the `struct Something`. This means, you can now call all these functions exposed by the struct like `get`, `take`, `mutate` from other modules. Otherwise, you would need to create your own public functions which exposes an API to modify the storage.

Answer (score 3):

decl_storage! generate a structure for each storage this structure implements the storage trait specified.

`$vis` specify the visibility of this struct.

note: that the getter `get($getter)` is a public function implemented on module, it is not affected by this `$vis`.

note: At the end all modules write to the unique trie storage, thus values are still accessible somehow by requesting the right key.

EDIT: I could add that the interest of having the structure of a storage public is that then other module can write to it directly by using the `Storage{Value, Map, ..}` trait.